# Balls from $0$ to $99$, probability of at least one repeated ball.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $100$ balls, each numbered from $0$ to $99$. What's the probability of having, at least, one repeated ball taken from a total of $10$ draws? The draws are done with reposition.

I know that we could do,

$$
\begin{split} 
P(\text{At least 1 repeated})
&=1-P(\text{None is repeated})\\
&=1-(100\times 99 \times ... 91)/100^{10}\\
&\approx 0.371843
\end{split}$$

However, how would I go about this without considering the complementary event?

When looking at the number of favourable cases, I'm thinking of:

Favourable $=$ possibilities with $1$ repeated number $+ \dots+$ possibilities with $10$ repeated numbers

Imagine I want to count the number of possibilities with two, and only two, repeated numbers. I can choose $100\times 99$ balls for the first $2$ draws. On the third, I can choose any of the $2$ previous numbers that came out, but then I would have to take that exact same number for the remaining draws. So, I would have $100\times 99\times 2 \times 1 \times ... \times 1$.

So, the formula I came up for $n$ repeated numbers was $f_n=\frac{100!}{100-(10-n+1)!}\times(10-n+1)$.

However, I get $P(\text{At least 1 repeated}) \approx 0.000757637$

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated ball" please?

Comment: @Axel I'm mean I take, for example ball numbered 10, and then I take that same ball, in a posterior draw. The draws are done with reposition.

Comment: Ok thank you! It is all clear for me now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your initial calculation please? In particular, why do you only go to 91 instead of 1 if you have 100 balls?

Comment: @JEdwards I'm sorry, I forgot to say that we're doing 10 draws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $10$ draws with only *two* repeated numbers, you state $100\times 99\times 2 \times 1 \times ... \times 1$ but that is not correct. Rather it is $ \displaystyle {100 \choose 2} \times (2^{10}-2)$ arrangements. We choose two numbers and then we have $ \displaystyle 2^{10}$ ways of arranging these two numbers across $10$ draws. But two of these arrangements will have only one of the selected numbers in all $10$ draws so we subtract those.

Now as you go to $3$ digits, it gets a bit complicated and then a bit more. So comes the savior - Principle of Inclusion Exclusion. Now that we know it is not possible to solve it by hand, we can at least simplify it a bit by using Stirling Number of the second Kind. Here is how you can look at it -

We have first selected two numbers and we now  have draws $1-10$ and at least one of the draws has each of the selected numbers.

Using Stirling Number of the Second kind gives us number of ways to assign draws to two unlabeled heaps. But as the selected numbers are distinct, we multiply it by $2!$ to label the heaps.

So finally using WolframAlpha for calculation, the desired probability is,

$ \displaystyle \frac{1}{100^{10}} \sum_{i=1}^{9} {100 \choose i} \cdot i! \cdot StirlingS2[10,i] \approx 0.37184349$

Comment: Hi Math Lover, could you explain a bit more the reasoning behind the 2^10-2, specifically the part where you subtract by 2? I didn't get it... Thanks;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. So you are with me till the point that we choose $2$ numbers out of $100$ in ${100 \choose 2}$ ways? Say we chose $1$ and $2$. Now that we have two numbers $1$ and $2$, each of the $10$ draws can be any of these two numbers so that makes $2^{10}$ ways. But please note that as each of these two numbers can be chosen independently for each of the draws so there is one arrangement where all of the $10$ draws are $1$ ($1111111111$), and there is one arrangement where all of the $10$ draws are $2$ ($2222222222$).

Comment: So $2^{10} - 2$ is the number of arrangements where both numbers are present in $10$ draws. Does it clarify?

Comment: Yes, thanks ;). What about the Stirling function? How did you get it, and why the S2 and not the S1?

Comment: I linked a wiki page in my answer. That will tell you more about Stirling Number of the second kind. S2, because it is Stirling Number of the second kind. Stirling number of the second kind is what gives us number of non-empty heaps of different permutations of objects.

Comment: +1. Ok, thanks ;)